# can't getting data from cursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have a `ListView` (in an `Activity` and not in a `ListActivity`) that utilizes a custom cursor adapter to get some data from my local db and show them inside the `ListView`.

```java
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id)
      {
            Log.i(tag, "position = " + position);
        Log.i(tag, "id is : " + id));
      }
});
```

Assume my database columns are the following :

> id, name, surname, dob, height, gender, placeOfBirth, maritalStatus.

However, I am showing in my listview (row.xml) only the name and surname.
But whenever the user clicks on a certain row in the list, I want to retrieve the rest of the data too, for example, the id, or the gender of the row clicked.

The issue is that, I am not showing all the info from the db row in my list, however, when the user presses on the list I need to retrieve some of the data for that list. How can I do that here ?

The below method does not work, because I am not in a ListActivity, and just Activity.

```java
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position,  id);

Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
c.moveToPosition(position);
//get the data...
}
```

Comment: I do not fully understand the first part of your question. About the second part: you do not need a ListActivity. Just store your adapater as a data member of your Activity class or Fragment.

Comment: @NobuGames I updated the question have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arg0` parameter in your `OnItemClickListener` **is** the `ListView`. However, you can just do

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            // This will get the cursor from the adapter, already moved to position
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mCursorAdapter.getItem(position)
            //get the data...
      }
});
```

Comment: where do you initialize the mCursorAdapter ? (it is already global you assume ??)

Comment: That's the adapter that you set in `lv.setAdapter()`

Comment: it tells me to cast as following :  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mCursorAdapter.getItem(position);

Comment: it works. thanks, I was using this, but I changed it as yours is less code : MyAdapter tempAdapter = (MyAdapter ) adapterView.getAdapter(); Cursor c = tempAdapter.getCursor();c.moveToPosition(position);  NO IDEA, how/why your method works though, some explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Inside the `getView` method you should use something like this

```
view.setTag(data); // you can pass here your specific data for each item
```

Supposing your data is just an integer, then you can get this value from the `onItemClick()` in this way:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Integer data = (Integer) view.getTag();
    // your operation
}
```

Comment: you mean, I put a hidden textView for the things I do not want to show, and get the values via the method you suggested ? sounds too much overhead.

Comment: No, I'm talking about using setTag for identify the item inside the list. So when you perform the click action on a certain item you can get the id of this item. Then you can use that id for accessing your data in database - IMPORTANT: in this case you should not use recycling item, or you need to update each recycled view with new tag

Comment: This is unnecessary data duplication. See my answer.